# Cannot deserialize ArrayList object out of String from nested XML to Java POJO using Jackson

Tags: java, json, xml, rest, jackson

I have a REST service that calls an external endpoint which returns XML response.

Project dependencies are basically Lombok, spring starter web and jackson.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
  <version>2.13.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the current XML response received once the endpoint is called:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Publication_MarketDocument xmlns="urn:iec62325.351:tc57wg16:451-3:publicationdocument:7:0">
   <mRID>032af514c4a34ede9911c84cda33a547</mRID>
   <revisionNumber>1</revisionNumber>
   <type>A44</type>
   <sender_MarketParticipant.mRID codingScheme="A01">10X1001A1001A450</sender_MarketParticipant.mRID>
   <sender_MarketParticipant.marketRole.type>A32</sender_MarketParticipant.marketRole.type>
   <receiver_MarketParticipant.mRID codingScheme="A01">10X1001A1001A450</receiver_MarketParticipant.mRID>
   <receiver_MarketParticipant.marketRole.type>A33</receiver_MarketParticipant.marketRole.type>
   <createdDateTime>2022-09-01T12:15:32Z</createdDateTime>
   <period.timeInterval>
      <start>2015-12-31T23:00Z</start>
      <end>2016-01-02T23:00Z</end>
   </period.timeInterval>
   <TimeSeries>
      <mRID>1</mRID>
      <businessType>A62</businessType>
      <in_Domain.mRID codingScheme="A01">10YCZ-CEPS-----N</in_Domain.mRID>
      <out_Domain.mRID codingScheme="A01">10YCZ-CEPS-----N</out_Domain.mRID>
      <currency_Unit.name>EUR</currency_Unit.name>
      <price_Measure_Unit.name>MWH</price_Measure_Unit.name>
      <curveType>A01</curveType>
      <Period>
         <timeInterval>
            <start>2015-12-31T23:00Z</start>
            <end>2016-01-01T23:00Z</end>
         </timeInterval>
         <resolution>PT60M</resolution>
         <Point>
            <position>1</position>
            <price.amount>16.50</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>2</position>
            <price.amount>15.50</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>3</position>
            <price.amount>14.00</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>4</position>
            <price.amount>10.01</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>5</position>
            <price.amount>8.97</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>6</position>
            <price.amount>12.23</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>7</position>
            <price.amount>12.10</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>8</position>
            <price.amount>14.00</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>9</position>
            <price.amount>5.00</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>10</position>
            <price.amount>10.01</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>11</position>
            <price.amount>14.50</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>12</position>
            <price.amount>5.00</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>13</position>
            <price.amount>6.00</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>14</position>
            <price.amount>11.05</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>15</position>
            <price.amount>21.00</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>16</position>
            <price.amount>25.00</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>17</position>
            <price.amount>31.20</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>18</position>
            <price.amount>34.02</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>19</position>
            <price.amount>35.00</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>20</position>
            <price.amount>34.50</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>21</position>
            <price.amount>34.03</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>22</position>
            <price.amount>30.00</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>23</position>
            <price.amount>28.13</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>24</position>
            <price.amount>21.80</price.amount>
         </Point>
      </Period>
   </TimeSeries>
   <TimeSeries>
      <mRID>2</mRID>
      <businessType>A62</businessType>
      <in_Domain.mRID codingScheme="A01">10YCZ-CEPS-----N</in_Domain.mRID>
      <out_Domain.mRID codingScheme="A01">10YCZ-CEPS-----N</out_Domain.mRID>
      <currency_Unit.name>EUR</currency_Unit.name>
      <price_Measure_Unit.name>MWH</price_Measure_Unit.name>
      <curveType>A01</curveType>
      <Period>
         <timeInterval>
            <start>2016-01-01T23:00Z</start>
            <end>2016-01-02T23:00Z</end>
         </timeInterval>
         <resolution>PT60M</resolution>
         <Point>
            <position>1</position>
            <price.amount>0.01</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>2</position>
            <price.amount>1.00</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>3</position>
            <price.amount>0.01</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>4</position>
            <price.amount>0.01</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>5</position>
            <price.amount>2.01</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>6</position>
            <price.amount>1.00</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>7</position>
            <price.amount>0.01</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>8</position>
            <price.amount>1.00</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>9</position>
            <price.amount>5.11</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>10</position>
            <price.amount>22.00</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>11</position>
            <price.amount>41.29</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>12</position>
            <price.amount>51.08</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>13</position>
            <price.amount>51.09</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>14</position>
            <price.amount>61.93</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>15</position>
            <price.amount>50.00</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>16</position>
            <price.amount>53.04</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>17</position>
            <price.amount>100.00</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>18</position>
            <price.amount>64.83</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>19</position>
            <price.amount>58.02</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>20</position>
            <price.amount>32.29</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>21</position>
            <price.amount>35.08</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>22</position>
            <price.amount>22.00</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>23</position>
            <price.amount>22.00</price.amount>
         </Point>
         <Point>
            <position>24</position>
            <price.amount>16.00</price.amount>
         </Point>
      </Period>
   </TimeSeries>
</Publication_MarketDocument>
```

And below are all the Java classes that I am using in order to map the above XML to POJOs.

PublicationMarketDocument class

```
@Data
public class PublicationMarketDocument {
    @JsonProperty("revisionNumber")
    private String revisionNumber;
    @JsonProperty("period.timeInterval")
    private TimeInterval timeInterval;
    @JsonProperty("TimeSeries")
    private List<TimeSeries> timeSeries;
}
```

TimeInterval class

```
@Data
public class TimeInterval {
    @JsonProperty("start")
    private String start;
    @JsonProperty("end")
    private String end;
}
```

TimeSeries class

```
@Data
public class TimeSeries {
    @JsonProperty("businessType")
    private String businessType;
    @JsonProperty("in_Domain.mRID")
    private String inDomain;
    @JsonProperty("out_Domain.mRID")
    private String outDomain;
    @JsonProperty("currency_Unit.name")
    private String currencyName;
    @JsonProperty("price_Measure_Unit.name")
    private String priceMeasureUnitName;
    @JsonProperty("curveType")
    private String curveType;
    @JsonProperty("Period")
    private Period period;
}
```

Period class

```
@Data
public class Period {

    @JsonProperty("timeInterval")
    private TimeInterval timeInterval;
    @JsonProperty("resolution")
    private String resolution;
    @JsonProperty("Point")
    private List<Point> point;
}
```

Point class

```
@Data
public class Point {
    @JsonProperty("position")
    String position;
    @JsonProperty("price.amount")
    String priceAmount;
}
```

Here is the controller class used to actually invoke the external API:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/")
@Slf4j
public class FetchController {

    @GetMapping(value = "day-ahead-prices", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<PublicationMarketDocument> getDayAheadPrices() {

        String localUrl = URL + "&periodStart=" + pStart + "&periodEnd=" + pEnd;

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<PublicationMarketDocument> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(localUrl, PublicationMarketDocument.class);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(response.getBody(), HttpStatus.OK);

    }
}
```

Here is the error received on app initiliazation:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class com.example.openvpp.models.MarketDataModel] and content type [text/xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.openvpp.models.TimeSeries` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('1'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.openvpp.models.TimeSeries` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('1')
 at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 16, column: 10] (through reference chain: com.example.openvpp.models.MarketDataModel["TimeSeries"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])] with root cause
```

Below approximate result is obtained only if we do not have the TimeSeries and Point fields as Lists in the caller classes. Once we wrap them as List<>, the problem occurs.

```
{
    "revisionNumber": "1",
    "period.timeInterval": {
        "start": "2015-12-31T23:00Z",
        "end": "2016-01-01T23:00Z"
    },
    "TimeSeries": {
        "businessType": "A62",
        "in_Domain.mRID": "10YCZ-CEPS-----N",
        "out_Domain.mRID": "10YCZ-CEPS-----N",
        "currency_Unit.name": "EUR",
        "price_Measure_Unit.name": "MWH",
        "curveType": "A01",
        "Period": {
            "timeInterval": {
                "start": "2015-12-31T23:00Z",
                "end": "2016-01-01T23:00Z"
            },
            "resolution": "PT60M",
            "Point": {
                "position": "24",
                "price.amount": "21.80"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main problem that I am facing is deserializing the nested XML fields to TimeSeries and Point List Objects. Already tried adding @JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY) to both of them with no success.

Also tried this annotation @JsonDeserialize(as=ArrayList.class, contentAs=Point.class) however error remains the same.

Is there an elegant way to do it at the moment and is this a drawback of jackson library itself?

I do not have control over the external XML endpoint. Furthermore I do not control an ObjectMapper instance since I want Jackson to do the mapping of the XML to Java POJOs entirely.

**PS** Adding here the final results obtained after @qdoot advised of using the `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)` annotation. Hope this helps for someone looking at this in the future.

```
{
    "revisionNumber": "1",
    "period.timeInterval": {
        "start": "2015-12-31T23:00Z",
        "end": "2016-01-02T23:00Z"
    },
    "TimeSeries": [
        {
            "businessType": "A62",
            "in_Domain.mRID": "10YCZ-CEPS-----N",
            "out_Domain.mRID": "10YCZ-CEPS-----N",
            "currency_Unit.name": "EUR",
            "price_Measure_Unit.name": "MWH",
            "curveType": "A01",
            "Period": {
                "timeInterval": {
                    "start": "2015-12-31T23:00Z",
                    "end": "2016-01-01T23:00Z"
                },
                "resolution": "PT60M",
                "Point": [
                    {
                        "position": "1",
                        "price.amount": "16.50"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "2",
                        "price.amount": "15.50"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "3",
                        "price.amount": "14.00"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "4",
                        "price.amount": "10.01"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "5",
                        "price.amount": "8.97"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "6",
                        "price.amount": "12.23"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "7",
                        "price.amount": "12.10"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "8",
                        "price.amount": "14.00"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "9",
                        "price.amount": "5.00"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "10",
                        "price.amount": "10.01"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "11",
                        "price.amount": "14.50"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "12",
                        "price.amount": "5.00"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "13",
                        "price.amount": "6.00"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "14",
                        "price.amount": "11.05"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "15",
                        "price.amount": "21.00"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "16",
                        "price.amount": "25.00"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "17",
                        "price.amount": "31.20"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "18",
                        "price.amount": "34.02"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "19",
                        "price.amount": "35.00"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "20",
                        "price.amount": "34.50"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "21",
                        "price.amount": "34.03"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "22",
                        "price.amount": "30.00"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "23",
                        "price.amount": "28.13"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "24",
                        "price.amount": "21.80"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "businessType": "A62",
            "in_Domain.mRID": "10YCZ-CEPS-----N",
            "out_Domain.mRID": "10YCZ-CEPS-----N",
            "currency_Unit.name": "EUR",
            "price_Measure_Unit.name": "MWH",
            "curveType": "A01",
            "Period": {
                "timeInterval": {
                    "start": "2016-01-01T23:00Z",
                    "end": "2016-01-02T23:00Z"
                },
                "resolution": "PT60M",
                "Point": [
                    {
                        "position": "1",
                        "price.amount": "0.01"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "2",
                        "price.amount": "1.00"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "3",
                        "price.amount": "0.01"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "4",
                        "price.amount": "0.01"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "5",
                        "price.amount": "2.01"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "6",
                        "price.amount": "1.00"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "7",
                        "price.amount": "0.01"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "8",
                        "price.amount": "1.00"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "9",
                        "price.amount": "5.11"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "10",
                        "price.amount": "22.00"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "11",
                        "price.amount": "41.29"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "12",
                        "price.amount": "51.08"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "13",
                        "price.amount": "51.09"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "14",
                        "price.amount": "61.93"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "15",
                        "price.amount": "50.00"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "16",
                        "price.amount": "53.04"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "17",
                        "price.amount": "100.00"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "18",
                        "price.amount": "64.83"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "19",
                        "price.amount": "58.02"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "20",
                        "price.amount": "32.29"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "21",
                        "price.amount": "35.08"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "22",
                        "price.amount": "22.00"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "23",
                        "price.amount": "22.00"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": "24",
                        "price.amount": "16.00"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code that actually makes the conversion with the ObjectMapper I assume...

Comment: @Stempler, please note that I do not have such code in the codebase. I would like to do the implementation without involving ObjectMapper explicitly and want Jackson to take care of the conversion from XML response above to Java POJOs.

Comment: What was missing from my post above was only the actual controller class, so I added it for sanity reasons although it is not essential in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try @JacksonXmlElementWrapper

```
   @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping=false)
   private List<Point> point;
```

Comment: This actually helped! I added above annotation with `useWrapping=false` to both the `List<Point> point` and `List<TimeSeries> timeSeries` fields. Now I have what I want without the need to use ObjectMapper explicitly for the conversion. Thank you @qdoot!